# How can I get the id of currently logged-in user in function beforeDelete() in cakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I want to access the `id` of currently logged in user

My `beforeDelete()` function in `/app/models/course.php`:

```
function beforeDelete() 
{
// Some code 
// code also sets value of $uid2

$uid = $this->Auth->user('id');    //this is line 86 in course.php

    if ($uid2 == $uid) {
            return true;
    } 
    else {
            return false;
    }
}
```

But during execution, I get the following error:

```
Notice (8): Undefined property: Course::$Auth [APP/models/course.php, line 86]
Fatal error: Call to a member function user() on a non-object in /var/www/some_path/app/models/course.php on line 86
```

Please suggest..

Comment: Components, such as the Auth component, are only available to controllers. So that's why you're getting errors. I'm not sure how to solve this in a clean way though.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Terr. The method suggested by burzum works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the id of the current logged in user with the data to the model from the controller.

```
$this->Model->data[$this->Model->alias]['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
```

In your beforeDelete() callback you can access it

```
$this->data[$this->alias]['user_id']
```

and do whatever you want there. I could give you further advice but your question is, to be honest, not very informative. Please be more specific about your goal in the future.